# Why "this.href" does not get the href value I assigned

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to get the value of the href as i need to pass a variable in query string

```
<a id="CA"  class="CA" href='<%#"mysecondpage.aspx?ID=" + Td1.InnerText %>'  
    onclick="return popitup(this.href)" runat="server">comment</a>
```

I have to open a popup in which the "mysecondpage" should be open with a value inside a query string but this.href returns blank value and i dont know why it is not working as it worked inside itemtemplate (gridview) i have used table and filled data with angularJS repeat.

this is my popitup function:

```
function popitup(url) {
    alert(url);
    // window.open(url+id,'popup', 'width=700,height=800,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Was beat to it....but it's an attribute, not a property of ````this````

Comment: even after accessing as property it is now coming null instead of nothing

Comment: `even after accessing as property` how?

Comment: Are you certain `<%#"mysecondpage.aspx?ID=" + Td1.InnerText %>` is actually outputting a value? Show us the rendered HTML.

Comment: yes it is check the answer given by VDWWD

Comment: If VDWWD answer solves your problem then it _wasn't_ outputting a value.

Comment: it is giving me the id =16 so what are you even asking i dont know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a DataBinding expression `<%# %>`. So you have to call `DataBind()` in the Page_Load explicitly.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What kind of a god are you it worked after it really helped me ...how to know more about databinding expression ...i never knew it is something like databinding expression .

Comment: There are [some more](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976112/introduction-to-asp-net-inline-expressions-in-the-net-framework). But basically you need a databinding expression inside a Control (<asp:. or html with runat=server) when you want to use a variable inside it. But usually you bind data inside an element in a Repeater, GridView etc, and then you always have to call `GridView1.DataBind()`. That ensures the nested controls also get bounded. That is why you usually never call `DataBind()` separately like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery,

Try this I hope it will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#CA').on('click' function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(url);
    });

});
```

Get back to me if is not working